# SOAP PHP return array value

Tags: php, soap

I am connecting to a webservice using SOAP and PHP.Now i getting result value as an array i think.

```
try
{
    $result = $soapClient->__soapCall("CreateVehicleInsurancePolicy", array($parameters), null, $soapHeaders, $output_headers);

}
```

When i print_r($output_headers);
it will print like

```
Array ( [SoapHeaderOut] => stdClass Object ( [intResponseCode] => 100 [strArMsg] => Ø§Ù„Ø±Ù…Ø² Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø±ÙˆØ±ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø¯Ø®Ù„ Ù„Ù„Ù…Ø§Ù„Ùƒ ØºÙŠØ± Ù…ÙˆØ¬ÙˆØ¯ ÙÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù„Ù Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø±ÙˆØ±ÙŠ [strEnMsg] => The entered traffic code for the owner does not exist in the traffic file. ) )
```

I want to print each these 3 varibles seperately.How can i do that...bcz i am very new to these things.

Comment: I think the returned data is UNICODE. Encode it first

Comment: I encoded using json and got     string '{"SoapHeaderOut":{"intResponseCode":177,"strArMsg":"\u0627\u0644\u0631\u0645\u0632 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0631\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u062e\u0644 \u0644\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u0643 \u063a\u064a\u0631 \u0645\u0648\u062c\u0648\u062f \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0644\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0631\u064a","strEnMsg":"The entered traffic code for the owner does not exist in the traffic file."}}' (length=427)

Comment: what result of $result?Where did you defined the $output_headers?

Comment: when i encode $result it showing like string '{}' (length=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try access like this

```
echo $output_headers['SoapHeaderOut']->intResponseCode;

echo $output_headers['SoapHeaderOut']->strArMsg;

echo $output_headers['SoapHeaderOut']->strEnMsg;
```